# Handle delete in EditText Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am facing a problem. I have 6 EditTexts. The content of each of them gives a total of 6 digits which is a password. If the password is correct, the user is being sent to another Activity. My problem is that if I try to delete, I am not able to handle a key press event, which will delete the content of each and every one of them, starting from the last.
I have implemented IOnKeyListener interface as follows:

```
public class MainActivity :Activity,   View.IOnKeyListener
{
   public bool OnKey(View v, Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && keyCode.Equals(Keycode.Del))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText ed = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText_vonalkod);
        ed.SetOnKeyListener(this);

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this snippet on a simulator and it worked for me. I got a callback to the method when I hit the del button and it was differentiated from other keypresses by the KeyCode. If your problem is something else, please explain in detail.

Comment: I am not able to get a callback to the method when I try do edit the EditText and the hit the del button